# Posting a comment to a facebook post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using the newest facebook SDK 3.8 for iOS. I want to post a comment to a wall post and I am having troubles. The following method I am using works maybe once or twice and then gives me the error:

```
 Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

I am not sure if it has to do with "overdoing" posting because I am only posting twice when this happens and on different posts each time. Like I said, it happens out of no where (Everytime before it is a success). So I believe it is my code. Can anyone tell me if I am doing this right?

Thank you!

```
-(BOOL) postComment: (NSString *) postID :(NSString *) userPostMessage;
{
__block BOOL value;
postID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/comments?message=%@",postID,userPostMessage];
[FBSession activeSession];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:postID parameters:0 HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    BOOL temp;
    if (error)
    {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        temp = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
        valueReturned = (NSString*)result;
        temp = FALSE;
    }
    value = temp;

}];
return value;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking before for login in and correct permissions ?

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski if by before you mean when they first logged in, then yes. Once they have logged in, and I have eventually collected both the read and publish permission I require, I do not ask for them again nor do I ask to login again (unless they logout). Like I said I have managed to successfully make a post but then it will fail on the second post. Thanks! P.S. I read somewhere perhaps the problem is with the startWithGraphPath getting called more than once...

Comment: Are you posting exactly same message ? Because it could be just Facebook spam protection. Try posting different message

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I assumed that much, So I did post with different text. Imagine having a "Post comment" button on every post. When the user (me) taps it and enters the message, the message is sent to the method above and posted successfully. Now, the user posts on another comment with a different message but this time it fails. Same code, different post, new object initialized for the method above... everything. Any other ideas? Thanks!